# How to merge folders during COPY from previous stage in dockerfile multistage builds?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm extracting my jar with `layertools` into the folder `/opt/app/extract`.
In the next stage, I want to just copy the full extract folder with all subfolders and files, but the application won't start then:

```
FROM $BUILD_IMAGE as build
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY src src
RUN mvn -B package
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/*.jar extract --destination extract/
    
FROM $RUNTIME_IMAGE
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract ./
```

Result:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
2022-03-24T11:36:27.297896617Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

What works is the following, but I'd like to prevent having to repeat all folders inside the `/extract/` path.
Can't I just `COPY` everything inside?

```
FROM $RUNTIME_IMAGE
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract/application/ ./
```

The problem here is that the working example copies the **content** from each subfolder into `/opt/app`. So to say a merge.

Question: is that possible with a single copy command, that just takes all subfiles/folders from `extract/` stage, and copies the content over?

Comment: If what is below is working... Have you tried to add the `/` after `COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract` in the example on top? As `COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract/ ./`

Comment: how about build a jar with dependencies?

Comment: Copy without the `/` should work. You can simply verify this if you add `RUN ls -la ./` after your `COPY` and build the image. Take this Dockerfile for instance `FROM debian:stretch-slim as builder
RUN mkdir /test
RUN cd /test && touch test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt test4.txt test5.txt && mkdir -p subdir/subdirinsubdir
RUN ls -la /test && ls -la /test/subdir

FROM debian:stretch-slim
COPY --from=builder /test /test
RUN ls -la /test && ls -la /test/subdir
CMD [ "bash" ]`. It will copy the files and directories recursively and correctly.

Comment: Good edit. Didn't catch it was a *merge* before.

Comment: docker COPY works exactly like you want. `COPY --from=build /opt/app/extract ./` copies everything inside extract, to `./`, stripping the parent. But you seem to want to strip one more level, thats not possible. You need to do that work beforehand in the first stage.